# jQuery window resize issue - height/width calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullscreen, window-resize

The issue is as such - I'm using jQuery to set the height of a container. I am using the plugin bgStretcher 3.1.2 to stretch an image to the dimensions of this container. In screenshot 1 the container I am reffering to is the area occupied y the brick wall image.

[image: screenshot 1]

The problem arises when you resize the browser, every 2nd time the resize fires the calculations for height/width are off by 15px (I have no idea where this number comes from), creating a gap to the right and bottom of the container as visible in Screenshot 2. This screenshot also includes the console readings of the height of the container as returned by Jquery, indicating the issue. So when you resize the container jitters like hell and potentially ends up with the aforementioned gap.

[image: screenshot 2]

I believe there is some sort of conflict happening between my code and the plugin as they're both bound to window resize.

This is the simple bit of code I'm using on my end:

```
    win.resize(function() {
        console.log(win.height());
        conH = win.height()-68;
        wrapper.css({
            height: conH+"px"
        })
    }).resize();
```

Comment: Does this happen on all browsers?

Comment: I have tested on firefox, chrome and safari and the issue occurs on all 3

Comment: Not sure then, i need to see it in action -- however have you tried a CSS alternative that works the same, like -- http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

```
function init_heght(element) {
    var y = $(window).height();
    $(element).css('height', y);
};

init_heght('#section-left-menu');
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.